# Assigning names in PropertyGrid controls

Tags: c#, ui-automation, propertygrid

I'm developing an application in C#, .NET Framework 4 and WPF. I'm using WPG library. Some UIs of the software is comprised of `PropertyGrid`. Those `PropertyGrid`s contain various controls like comboboxes, check boxes, text boxes etc. Example:

```
    private SensorType _sensorType = SensorType.Ambient;
    [Category("Device Info")]
    [DisplayName("Sensor Type")]
    public SensorType SensorInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _sensorType;
        }

        set
        {
            this._sensorType = value;
        }
    }

    private ChipSize _chipSize = ChipSize.EEProm16K; 
    [Category("Device Info"),
    DisplayName("EEPROM Type"),
    DescriptionAttribute("The size of the EEPROM")]
    public ChipSize Chip
    {
        get
        {
            return _chipSize;
        }

        set
        {
            this._chipSize = value;
        }
    }
```

Another developer is going to write some automation code for test automation. He needs to access these properties to freely set various values. For example, there are 9 possible `SensorType` in the example above and he wants to set any of those values in `Sensor Type` combo box.

How can I assign names to these properties so that it can be easily found in test automation code?

Comment: The properties already have a name and can be readily accessed in any test project.  If he wants to write tests for a PropertyGrid then he's wasting his time, it is already a well-tested control.

Comment: @HansPassant: not sure what you're saying. he's not testing the property grid, he's writing automation tests for the software. to do that he needs to access window controls. when the control is inside a PropertyGrid, how that can be accessed?